# Find a basis for $U+W$ and $U\cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let

$$W = \operatorname{span}([2,1,0,1], [0,0,1,0])
\\V = \operatorname{span}([1,2,1,3], [3,1,-1,4])$$

I need to find a basis and the dimension for $U+V$ and $U\cap V$. For $U+V$ I tried:

$$U+V = \{u+v|u\in U, v\in V\} = \alpha_1[2,1,0,1]+\alpha_2[0,0,1,0] + \alpha_3[1,2,1,3] + \alpha_4[3,1,-1,4]$$

Therefore I have to find if this set is linearly independent or not. If it is, then it's a basis for $U+V$.

By transforming this to a system, we have:

$$\begin{cases}2\alpha_1 + 0\alpha_2 + 1\alpha_3 + 3\alpha_4 = 0\\1\alpha_1 + 0\alpha_2 + 2\alpha_3 + 1\alpha_4 = 0\\0\alpha_1 + 1\alpha_2 + 1\alpha_3 -1\alpha_4 = 0\\1\alpha_1 + 0\alpha_2 + 3\alpha_3 + 4\alpha_4 = 0\end{cases}$$

By solving this system, we should get the answer. Is there a easy way to solve it?

For the case $U\cap W$ I can't see how to act. Maybe if i find $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, \beta_4$ such that 
$$\beta_1[2,1,0,1]+\beta_2[0,0,1,0] = \beta_3[1,2,1,3] + \beta_4[3,1,-1,4]$$
I should get what the intersection is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an efficient approach: row reduce the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
2&0&1&3\\
1&0&2&1\\
0&1&1&-1\\
1&0&3&4
}
$$
The columns corresponding to the pivots form a basis of $U+V$. The others form a basis of $U\cap V$.

Comment: How is this method called? I need to study why it works. By the way, thank you by this :)

Comment: I don't know of any name for it. The reason it works is that row-reduction preserves the null-space.

Comment: Nice. When I solved for the $\beta$s, I got they all $0$. This means there's no intersection? Then, what is the basis?

Comment: This means that the intersection is $\{0\}$, which has the empty set as its basis.

Comment: Thank you so much! You said the other form a basis for the intersection. What would be, then, the others, in this rref?

Comment: If the $\beta$s had to all be zero, then your rref must be the identity.  So, every column is a pivot column.  So, there are no other columns.  So, the basis of $U \cap V$ consists of no vectors.

Comment: Hi @BenGrossmann would you mind explaining why your method works? I recently asked a similar (more general) question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960942/basis-of-u-cap-v-via-row-echelon-form

Comment: @jlammy There is a list of a lot of similar questions given in the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906374/81360), perhaps you will find one of this posts helfpul